# How to split a huge rdd and broadcast it by turns?

Tags: apache-spark

**Description**:

Our spark version is 1.4.1

we want to join two huge RDD, one of them with skew data. so the spark rdd operation join may lead memory problem. We try to split one of smaller one to several pieces then broadcast them in batches. On each broadcast turn, we try to collect one part of smaller rdd to driver, then save it to HashMap, then broadcast the HashMap. Each executor use the broadcast value to do map operation with the bigger rdd. We implement our skew data join through this way.

But when it process broadcast value in each turn. we find that we can not destroy our broadcast value after processing. if we use broadcast.destroy(), next turn we processing data will
trigger errors. like this:

```
java.io.IOException: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Attempted to use Broadcast(6) after it was destroyed (destroy at xxx.java:369)
```

we have viewed the source code of spark, and find this problem is leaded by rdd dependency relationship. if rdd3 -> rdd2 -> rdd1 (the arrow shows dependency). and rdd1 is produced by using broadcast variable named b1, rdd2 used b2. when producing rdd3, the source code shows it need to serialize b1 and b2. if b1 or b2 is destroyed before rdd3 producing process. It will cause a failure which I list above.

**Question**:

Does it exist way can let rdd3 forget its dependency and make it don't require b1, b2, only required rdd2 during its producing process?

Or Does it exist way to deal with skew join problem?

by the way, we have set checkpoint for each turn. and set spark.cleaner.ttl to 600. the problem are still there. if we don't destroy broadcast variable, executor will lost in 5th turn.

our code is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < times; i++) {
    JavaPairRDD<Tuple2<String, String>, Double> prevItemPairRdd = curItemPairRdd;
    List<Tuple2<String, Double>> itemSplit = itemZippedRdd
            .filter(new FilterByHashFunction(times, i))
            .collect();

    Map<String, Double> itemSplitMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
    for (Tuple2<String, Double> item : itemSplit) {
        itemSplitMap.put(item._1(), item._2());
    }
    Broadcast<Map<String, Double>> itemSplitBroadcast = jsc
            .broadcast(itemSplitMap);

    curItemPairRdd = prevItemPairRdd
            .mapToPair(new NormalizeScoreFunction(itemSplitBroadcast))
            .persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY());
    curItemPairRdd.count();

    itemSplitBroadcast.destroy(true);
    itemSplit.clear();

}
```

Comment: So you tried joining two RDDs, it didn't work, and you decided to reimplement joining yourself. I question that decision. Why do you think your join implementation will be better than Spark's? I'd rather suggest you work out the issues with the join. Post those problems as Stack Overflow questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally I would try a little bit different approach. Lets start with a small simulated dataset

```scala
import scala.util.Random
Random.setSeed(1)

val left = sc.parallelize(
  Seq.fill(200)(("a", Random.nextInt(100))) ++ 
  Seq.fill(150)(("b",  Random.nextInt(100))) ++ 
  Seq.fill(100)(Random.nextPrintableChar.toString, Random.nextInt(100))
)
```

and count by key:

```scala
val keysDistribution = left.countByKey
```

Further lets assume that the second RDD is uniformly distributed:

```scala
val right = sc.parallelize(
  keysDistribution.keys.flatMap(x => (1 to 5).map((x, _))).toSeq)
```

and set threshold of number of values we can process per key to 10:

```scala
val threshold = 10
```

1. Use **surrogate keys** to increase granularity.

   Idea is quite simple. Instead of joining `(k, v)` pairs lets use `((k, i), v)` where `i` is an integer which depends on a threshold and a number of elements for a given `k`.

   ```scala
   val buckets = keysDistribution.map{
     case (k, v) => (k -> (v / threshold + 1).toInt)
   }

   // Assign random i to each element in left
   val leftWithSurrogates = left.map{case (k, v) => {
     val i = Random.nextInt(buckets(k))
     ((k, i), v)
   }}

   // Replicate each value from right to i buckets
   val rightWithSurrogates = right.flatMap{case (k, v) => {
     (0 until buckets(k)).map(i => ((k, i), v))
   }}

   val resultViaSurrogates = leftWithSurrogates
     .join(rightWithSurrogates)
     .map{case ((k, _), v) => (k, v)}
   ```
2. **Divide and conquer** - split processing of frequent and infrequent keys.

   First lets join using infrequent keys:

   ```scala
   val infrequentLeft = left.filter{
     case (k, _) => keysDistribution(k) < threshold
   }

   val infrequentRight = right.filter{
     case (k, _) => keysDistribution(k) < threshold
   }

   val infrequent = infrequentLeft.join(infrequentRight)
   ```

   Next lets process each frequent key separately:

   ```scala
   val frequentKeys = keysDistribution
     .filter{case (_, v) => v >= threshold}
     .keys

   val frequent = sc.union(frequentKeys.toSeq.map(k => {
     left.filter(_._1 == k)
       .cartesian(right.filter(_._1 == k))
       .map{case ((k, v1), (_, v2)) => (k, (v1, v2))}
   }))
   ```

   Finally lets union both subsets:

   ```scala
   val resultViaUnion = infrequent.union(frequent)
   ```

Quick sanity check:

```scala
val resultViaJoin = left.join(right).sortBy(identity).collect.toList

require(resultViaUnion.sortBy(identity).collect.toList == resultViaJoin)
require(resultViaSurrogates.sortBy(identity).collect.toList == resultViaJoin)
```

Obviously this more a sketch than a complete solution but should give you some idea how to proceed. The biggest advantage over `broadcast` it that it removes driver bottleneck.

> Does it exist way can let rdd3 forget its dependency and make it don't require b1, b2, only required rdd2 during its producing process?

You use checkpoints and forced computation but it will still fail if any partition is lost.

Comment: A newbie question: it looks like if the data in `left` rdd is highly skewed (i.e. many instances of the same key), then the size of the `rightWithSurrogates` rdd will be much larger than the original `right` rdd. So are we complicating the problem from the memory point of view. My guess is that there won't be much adverse effect since the key distribution is near to uniform inspite of large size (so no single executor will have bear a large workload). Just wanted to confirm if my understanding is correct.