# Spark imbalanced partitions after leftOuterJoin

Tags: performance, apache-spark, partitioning, rdd, outer-join

I have a pattern like this...  psuedo-code, but I think it makes sense...

```
type K  //  key, function of records in B

class A             //  compact data structure
val a: RDD[(K, A)]  //  many records 

class B {          //  massive data structure
  def funcIter     // does full O(n) scans of huge data structure
}
val b: RDD[(K,B)]  //  comparatively few records
val emptyB = new B("", Nil, etc.)

val C: RDD[(A,B)] = {
  a
  .leftOuterJoin(b, 1.5x increase in partitions)
  .map{ case (k, (val_a, option_b)) => (val_a, option_b.getOrElse(emptyB)) }
  .map{ case (val_a, val_b) => (val_a, val_b.funcIter(val_a.attributes)) }
}
```

My problem is that records in val b vary enormously in size with some quite enormous, and since it's a leftOuterJoin, each of those records is replicated 1,000's or 10,000's of times to join to val a...  so it's not just that there are large values in b to handle, but that the worst case records in b end up copied many times in one partition after the join.  So the worse partitions are almost exclusively made up of many copies of only the worse case values from b.  So my last few partitions take ages to work through while most of my enormous cluster sits idle, draining my wallet.

Is there anything I can do to modify this pattern...  try broadcasting b and joining with a in place (it's probably too big)....  or split partitions after the join maybe splitting copies of the worst b vals apart into different partitions without doing another shuffle...  like the opposite of a coalesce so at least multiple executors on the same core instance (I have 3 executors per core instance) can work on those records in parallel?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to split a huge rdd and broadcast it by turns?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34656338/how-to-split-a-huge-rdd-and-broadcast-it-by-turns)